# Converting Real Date into a fire date string for Location notification on ios

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Let me try this again being more clear, my apologies.
    \
I am looking at trying to add a date specific reminder to my photo assignment app in iOS. I'd love to be able to have it so it will fire a reminder on exact dates of the year that will direct them to the assignments for that time of year

For example:

Dec 31st-New Years Eve-shoot fireworks, parties
July 1st-Canada Day-shoot celebrations, fireworks
October 30th-before halloween-shoot pumpkins, costumes
December 15th-Christmas lights!

Etc.

I already have a daily reminder set up that fires at 9am every day reminding them to get an assignment, which is turned on or off at the users desire by a toggle switch in the settings bundle. I was hoping to have another one for the "holiday reminders"

Here is my current code for the daily reminder:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calender components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit)
                                                       fromDate:currentDate];

        NSDateComponents *temp = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

        [temp setYear:[dateComponents year]];
        [temp setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
        [temp setDay:[dateComponents day]];
        [temp setHour: 9];
        [temp setMinute:00];

        NSDate *fireTime = [calender dateFromComponents:temp];
        [temp release];

        // set up the notifier 
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

        localNotification.fireDate = fireTime;
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

How do I covert an actual date (December 31st) to a **fireDate =**  variable/string?

I hope that is more clear.  I have searched already and have not been able to find the answer.
Thank you

Noel Chenier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the year, month and day manually in when creating your fireTime.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calender components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit)
                                                   fromDate:currentDate];

    NSDateComponents *temp = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

    [temp setYear:2013];
    [temp setMonth:12];
    [temp setDay:31];
    [temp setHour: 9];
    [temp setMinute:00];

    NSDate *fireTime = [calender dateFromComponents:temp]; // December 31st 2013 9:00
    [temp release];

    // set up the notifier 
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    localNotification.fireDate = fireTime;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

Comment: thank you nizx. and to have this repeat every year, do I just add:

localNotification.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;

correct?